# Swift 4, Segue don't pass data

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I start learn swift and I'm stuck with this demo project. It should works, because I did everything like in videos, but somehow it didn't pass the data  between the view controllers.

ViewControllel.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var activeRow = 0

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 4

}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->  UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    cell.textLabel?.text = "Row \(indexPath.row)"
    return cell

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toSecondViewController", sender: nil)
    activeRow = indexPath.row
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toSecondViewController" {
        if let secondViewController = segue.destination as? SecondViewController {
        secondViewController.activeRow = activeRow
        }
    }
}
}
```

SecondViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

var activeRow: Int = 0

@IBOutlet weak var labelActiveRow: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    labelActiveRow.text = String(activeRow)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

After this, when I tap on any row, the label shows only "0", not the activeRow.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update this method assign **activeRow = indexPath.row** first

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    activeRow = indexPath.row
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toSecondViewController", sender: nil)  
}
```